# Grabbing user IDs through a nested form for use in custom attribute writer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, nested-forms

I'm trying to grab ONLY the ids of the users checked in my nested form.  I use these ids to update an attribute in my ListsUsers join table.  Right now, what I have grabs values of all the users belonging to the list regardless of whether or not their checkboxes are checked or unchecked.  I need unchecked boxes to be ignored.

Here is my nested form:

```
<%= form_for(@list) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :users do |users_fields| %>
    <%= users_fields.object.name %>
      <%= users_fields.check_box :id %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my List.rb

```
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lists_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :lists_users

  def users_attributes=(users_attributes)
    binding.pry
    #users_attributes should be a hash with of the users checked in the form
  end
end
```

And my ListsController.rb strong params

```
def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:name, :list_type, invites_attributes: [:email, :status], users_attributes: [:id, :name])
end
```

and here is the HTML output from my form checkboxes

```
First User
<input name="list[users_attributes][0][id]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="list[users_attributes][0][id]" id="list_users_attributes_0_id">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="list[users_attributes][0][id]" id="list_users_attributes_0_id">

Second User
<input name="list[users_attributes][1][id]" type="hidden" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="list[users_attributes][1][id]" id="list_users_attributes_1_id">
```

With the first person checked, and the second person UNchecked this is the value of users_attributes when I pry in users_attributes=

```
{"0"=>{"id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"2"}
```

I would expect to only have the first value {"id"="1}

And here is the output with the first 2 users checked, and the last one unchecked:

```
{"0"=>{"id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"3"}}
```

Here is the console output at form submit up until I hit the pry:

```
Started PATCH "/lists/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-21 00:08:43 -0800
Processing by ListsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XXXXXX==", "list"=>
{"users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"id"=>"3"}}}, "commit"=>"Update List", "id"=>"1"}
  List Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."id" = ? 
LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
```

Comment: And what is your console output upon submission of your form? (Please add to question.)

Comment: sorry about that.  updated it.

Comment: Can you show what your actual console log shows instead of your pry? Perhaps your `list_params` is incorrect.

Comment: Alright friend. Well, clearly there's something munged with your `form_for` and specifically with `users_fields.check_box :id`. Sadly, too late over here for me to help you. Hopefully, someone brilliant will happen along.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Very much appreciate you taking a look.  Have a good night!

Answer (score 1):

My Solution:

I passed the IDs as a hidden field...

```
<%= form_for(@list) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :users, @list.users do |user_field| %>
    <%= user_field.hidden_field :id %>
    <%= user_field.object.name %>
    <%= user_field.check_box :enable %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Then added an `enable` attribute to the User model...

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :lists_users
  has_many :lists, through: :lists_users

  attr_accessor :enable
end
```

And now I can determine which IDs to keep and which ones to discard based on their `:enable` value...

```
def users_attributes=(users_attributes)
    admin_user_ids = []
    users_attributes.values.each do |user_attribute|
      if user_attribute.values[1] == "1"
        user_ids << user_attribute.values[0].to_i
      end
    end
    join_entries = ListsUser.jointables(self.id)
    join_entries.each do |entry|
      if user_ids.include?(entry.user_id)
        entry.update(admin: true)
      else
        entry.update(admin: false)
      end
    end
   end
```